# make error when installing `ruby-1.8.7-p334` with `rvm` on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, makefile, installation, rvm

Some of my Ruby gems stopped working after installing Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6). I also installed Xcode (to get `make`) and get the following error when installing `ruby-1.8.7-p334` with `rvm`. I was able to succesfully install it when running Leopard. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Macintosh:haloror patelc75$ rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p334

Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/patelc75/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.8.7-p334 - #fetching
ruby-1.8.7-p334 - #extracted to /Users/patelc75/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p334 (already extracted)
ruby-1.8.7-p334 - #configuring
ruby-1.8.7-p334 - #compiling
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /Users/patelc75/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p334/make.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

Macintosh:haloror patelc75$ more /Users/patelc75/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p334/make.log

[2011-08-23 17:21:55] make
gcc -g -O2  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common    -DRUBY_EXPORT  -L.    main.o dmydln.o libruby-static.a -ldl -lobjc   -o miniruby
Undefined symbols:
"_Init_ext", referenced from:
  _require_libraries in libruby-static.a(ruby.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [miniruby] Error 1
```

Comment: have you tried any other patchlevel of 1.8.7 ? ruby-1.8.7-p352 for example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check the log file at /Users/patelc75/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p334/make.log
readline may be the issue most of the time. to fix that please do

`rvm pkg install readline`

before that you might want to do

`rvm remove 1.8.7

rvm cleanup`

Comment: Thanks, Ram! This worked: rvm pkg install readline; rvm cleanup all; rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p334