# Error running 'make' whilst installing Ruby through RVM on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, makefile, rvm

This is my first time using Ruby. I became aware not to use sudo to install Gems so I followed this tutotrial (http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac) to install RVM so that I could update my version of Ruby and then install Middleman (http://middlemanapp.com/).

RVM installation worked, but when installing Ruby 1.9.3 at the '#compiling' stage I get the following error:

> Error running 'make', please read
>   /Users/Mark/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/make.log There has been an error
>   while running make. Halting the installation.

I opened the log file and unlike a lot of other issues I've seen, the file doesn't contain references to 'readline' but to 'compiling' which I assume relates to the '#compiling' stage of the Ruby install. Below is the output to make.log:

```
[2013-02-12 09:04:26] make
    CC = clang
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = clang -dynamic -bundle
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/Users/Mark/.rvm/usr/include -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin12.2.0 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  
    SOLIBS = 
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling dmyencoding.c
compiling version.c
compiling dmyversion.c
compiling miniprelude.c
compiling array.c
compiling bignum.c
bignum.c:2732:26: warning: while loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
        while (--ny && !zds[ny]); ++ny;
                                ^
bignum.c:2732:26: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
1 warning generated.
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
compiling complex.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling enum.c
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling load.c
compiling proc.c
compiling file.c
compiling gc.c
gc.c:3060:1: warning: unused function 'chain_finalized_object' [-Wunused-function]
chain_finalized_object(st_data_t key, st_data_t val, st_data_t arg)
^
1 warning generated.
compiling hash.c
compiling inits.c
compiling io.c
compiling marshal.c
compiling math.c
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
compiling pack.c
compiling parse.c
compiling process.c
compiling random.c
compiling range.c
compiling rational.c
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
regparse.c:582:15: error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'st_index_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    return t->num_entries;
    ~~~~~~ ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [regparse.o] Error 1
```

If I run 'make --version' I get the following output:

> GNU Make 3.81 Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc. This
>   is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
>   PURPOSE.
>
> This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

I'm struggling to find an exact matching issue, so if anyone could help that would be great.

Cheers,

Mark.

Comment: Hello Mark, try a clean install and see if the error is reproduced. You can use [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/#osx). It's based on RVM too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot compile ruby 1.9.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592945/cannot-compile-ruby-1-9-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed some of the advice here and in other posts linked and Googled, but in the end, updating GCC via Homebrew is what finally got the Ruby installation to complile and complete.

Specific link I used for updating GCC: [Installing Ruby on Mac OS X 10.8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662569/installing-ruby-on-mac-os-x-10-8-2)

So thanks for all the help, I can't be sure if it was a combination of all the updates and cleanup as well as GCC or just GCC, but I'm up and running.

Comment: This answer on superuser covered updating GCC via homebrew, and worked for me: http://superuser.com/a/546778

Comment: @KevinC. Yeah thats the way I did it. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't see the error it is in fact caused by readline. As mentioned by atmosx I'd remove the default MAC OS X install of ruby and follow the process from the beginning.

Or following this https://rvm.io/packages/readline/ to help resolve readline. Also for reference look at this previous question: [Error running make when installing Ruby 1.8.7-p302 via RVM on Mac OS 10.5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338371/error-running-make-when-installing-ruby-1-8-7-p302-via-rvm-on-mac-os-10-5-8)

> So complete steps are:

```
rvm pkg install readline 
rvm remove 1.8.7 
rvm cleanup all 
rvm install 1.8.7 -C –with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Thanks to Andrew at http://anlek.com/2011/01/rvm-install-1-8-7-p330-fails/ for the pointer.

Comment: I don't think you deserved a down vote there! I followed this amongst other things and have managed to get Ruby installed and working.